# How to make clipboard ring appear in VS2008 toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio

It seems as if making the clipboard ring appear in the VS2008 toolbox is pretty elusive.  Does anyone know how to turn this on ?  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> works fine, but I'd like to see what on the ring.

Answer (score 1):

You should give [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) a try. It saves everything you put in your clipboard into an sqlite database. A shortcut pops it up and shows the history of your clippings.

The nice thing is that you can instantly search in this window through all your clippings.

I set it up to remeber everything in my clipboard for 60 days and made a habit of copying everything that might be usefull. That way I can quickly find that particular SQL statement, i did last week. Just dont search for "select" ;-)

Try it for some days and you will be amazed. There is also a [portable Version](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ditto-cp/Ditto_Portable_3_15_4_0.zip?download)

Answer (score 0):

If you drag text to the toolbox doesn't it appear?

Comment: Text does indeed appear when you drag to the toolbar - which is useful, I guess.  But it is not the same as the old clipboard ring toolbox tab that automatically had everything that you copied on to clipboard.

Comment: I see.. I never used this, I like the new behavior personally.

Answer (score 0):

It was removed in Visual Studio 2005. I'm trying to find a source for this.