# How do you make the Clipboard Ring display in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

If I try to add a tab to the toolbox and name it 'Clipboard Ring', I get an error message that says a tab by that name already exists. Is there any way to get it to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this, the tab was removed from newer versions of Visual Studio:
[How to make clipboard ring appear in VS2008 toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74604/how-to-make-clipboard-ring-appear-in-vs2008-toolbox)

Probably they're keeping the name reserved in case they ever want to bring it back.

You can however still drag text to the Toolbox tab and drop it there for later use.

I use Control+Shift+Ins to cycle through the ring.  Control+Shift+V works too.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

or

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>

Comment: This works for pasting items from the Clipboard Ring. Do you know of a way to remove items individually from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select your text and drag that onto your toolbox window. Just double clicking the text in the toolbar to include. I find it easier when I need to copy the text at different places. Refer this for more details [here](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/09/visual-studio-clipboard-ring-ctrl-shift-v.html)